# Does a Ranger's animal companion level up when multiclassing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, ranger, character-advancement, animal-companions

I'm currently playing a level 4 ranger and I'm thinking about multi-classing. I want to know if my animal companion gains a level when I take a level that isn't in Ranger?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Have you taken the [tour]? This is a great first question, I edited it to fix up a few minor typos and grammar errors. If you disagree with my changes you can [edit] the post to better suit your question. Welcome and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Lyra what other class are you multiclassing into?

Answer (score 3):

It **depends** on what animal you choose from the classes and how the class ability that give you an animal companion or a mount (or whatever) is written.

Quoting from animal companion:

> [Animal Companion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/)
>
> **An animal companion’s abilities are determined by the druid’s level** and its animal racial traits.
>
> [...] The druid’s class levels **stack with levels of any other classes** that are entitled to an animal companion for the purpose of determining the companion’s statistics.

Now, check the classes you are taking. I quote here few examples:

> Ranger
>
> [...] This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability (which is part of the Nature Bond class feature), except that the **ranger’s effective druid level is equal to his ranger level –3.**
>
> Druid
>
> [...] The second option is to form a close bond with an animal companion. A druid may begin play with any of the animals listed in Animal Choices. This animal is a loyal companion that accompanies the druid on her adventures.

In the druid case, ofcourse, there is no explicit state about druid effective level since...well you are a druid so your class levels **are** druid levels.

> Cavalier
>
> A cavalier gains the service of a loyal and trusty steed to carry him into battle. This mount functions as a druid’s animal companion, using the **cavalier’s level as his effective druid level. [...]**

Now, a game example:

We have a character who is ranger 4/cavalier 4/druid 1...how much strong is his horse animal companion?
It's simple!

The ranger states  his druid level are equal to his ranger level -3...and since he is a ranger 4 we can say he count as a druid 1 in regard of his animal companion.

The cavalier states he uses all his levels as druid levels in regard to his mount so, in this case, we count as a druid 4 in regard to animal companion.

The druid is the druid so no need to check.

Take all the numbers up we have 1+4+1 and the result is our horse animal companion is a level 6 animal companion (based on druid table ofcourse).

In addiction to all of this here is a faq talking about stacking animal companion levels:

[Animal companion level stack? FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qqn)

Comment: with boon companion, a druid can have an effective druid level higher than his own - very useful for the beastmaster archetype.

Comment: Well he is not asking for feats but about stacking level from different classes. Anyway, boon companion, does not work as you are writing here. Generally speaking the boon companion feat clearly state that "[...] to a maximum effective druid level equal to your character level. ". In short, if you are a druid 6 and take boon companion the feat will do nothing for you. If you instead are druid 6/fighter 4 and take boon companion the feat will count you as a druid 10 even if the fighter class has nothing to do with animal companion at all (normally at least)

Comment: A druid with beastmaster archetype has very likely multiple animal companions of a lower level. that was what I was aiming for. A druid 6 with a 2 and 4th level animal woulf end with a 6 and 4th level one

Comment: Maybe is a cherry picked archetype that work differently but in general does not treat your level "higher" than his own if your class is only druid that's what i'm saying

Comment: it's a fringe case where one distributes his druid level first, then applies the feat, which leads to a cummulated higher druid level

Comment: Its not really a *fringe case*, its a common build. Especially considering how companions grant you two big combat benefits: 1) You dont need to resurrect them should they get killed, so they are great tanks. 2) You get to act more than once per turn. *Master* summoners are great for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

### They do not

You need to take levels on a class that grants you an animal companion in order to them to level up, as the class abilities that grant an animal companion usually say something along the words:

> This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability

Which, in the druid class, says:

> Unlike normal animals of its kind, an animal companion’s Hit Dice, abilities, skills, and feats advance **as the druid advances in level**.

However, that can easily be fixed with the [Boon Companion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/boon-companion/) feat:

> The abilities of your animal companion or familiar are calculated as though your class were 4 levels higher, to a maximum effective druid level equal to your character level.

Comment: This is not true. Animal companions level always stack since you can't be counted, for example, as a druid level 3 and druid level 5 at the same time. If you are a druid 5/ranger 5...you count as a druid level 7 for your animal companion.

Comment: I simply used the wrong word there. **the** instead of **a**. Both druids and rangers are **a** class that grants animal companions. The OP didnt state which class he will be multiclassing into, so I cant assume its one that also grants animal companions.

Comment: removed the downvote after your correction, as you can say the sense of your answer now is totally different